# Conceptual doubt in Superfluidity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity, bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity

I'm trying to understand superfluidity from these [Caltech notes](http://www.cmp.caltech.edu/refael/phys127c/) on Advanced Statistical Physics (Week 1, Section IV: Landau Criterion for Superfluidity) -

> So far it is not clear why a moving superfluid doesn’t dissipate its
> kinetic energy. The spectrum of excitations is not gapped (which would
> be a sufficient condition for superflow), even though the number of
> low lying excitations is decreased relative to a non-interacting BEC.

**Question** - Why would a gapped excitation spectrum be a sufficient condition for superflow? (I understand *a gapped excitation spectrum* as simply a spectrum of allowed energy/momentum states that is NOT continuous but rather like a discrete band). I don't know where I am conceptually going wrong.

Comment: One way to see this is to continue reading. A gapped spectrum satisfies Landau's criterion and automatically gives a non-zero critical velocity.

Answer (score 0):

A superfluid has an energy gap from strong interatomic repulsion at short distances that prevents viscosity until the superfluid reaches a critical value of the excitation energy of the atoms.

https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1307/1307.4892.pdf
"The state of atoms in the liquid 4 He is characterized by wave functions and the discrete energy spectrum resulting in formation of s – and p- zones corresponding to the ground and excited states of helium atoms, respectively, separated by a gap. The width of the gap in 4 He system equals ~8.5K at T=0"

Comment: Not sure about this paper. Superfluid liquid helium is gapless, due to phonon excitations.